# Extjs4 : How to I get the Component from HTMLElement?

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm student with EXTJS4..

First, Please see this code.. This is My Ext.Img Item..

```
 var paddleItem = {
    xtype     : 'image',
    src       : "lib/Image/Paddle.png",
    x         : 0,
    y         : 0,
    draggable : true,
    index     : 0,
    id        : 'paddleItem',
    name      : 'Paddle',
    width     : 100,
    height    : 100,
    listeners : {
        dblclick : {
            element : 'el',
            fn : function(){
                conditionWindow.show();
            }
        },
        click : {
            element : 'el',
            fn : function(e,t,eOpts) {
                propertyForm.items.items[0].setValue('This is My Text');
                alert(t.id);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

When Click This Item, I wanna Get the this Item's Property(e.g. paddleItem.x, paddleItem.index)

But, There Click's param 't' is HTML Element.

So, I think.. 'I get the Item from HTML Element'

But I don't know how to get...

What can i do for this Problem?

Sorry to My fool English..

If you can't UnderStand, Please Comment to me..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all see what's the scope of handlers you're creating. Add the following code before alert function:

```
console.log(this)
```

And check browser console to see what object is being reported.